# Programa en C++ deja de funcionar

Tags: c++

Se nos pidió desarrollar un programa que enseñe inglés. Ya está listo, pero el problema es que al cabo de determinado tiempo de estar ejecutándose el programa, deja de funcionar y dice que se debe cerrar el programa. ¿Por qué pasa eso?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro.h>

using namespace std;
int Menu();
int Practica1();
int Practica2();
int Practica3();
int Practica4();
int Practica5();
int Practica6();
int Practica7();
int Pregunta2();
int Pregunta3();
int Pregunta4();
int Pregunta5();
int Pregunta6();
int Pregunta7();
int Pregunta8();
int Pregunta9();
int Pregunta10();
int Contador();
int contador=0, c1=0, c2=0, c3=0, c4=0, c5=0, c6=0, c7=0, c8=0, c9=0, c10=0;
bool finalizar=true;
bool continuar=true;
bool opcion=true;

BITMAP *fondo;
BITMAP *practice;
BITMAP *quizz;
BITMAP *practice1;
BITMAP *quizz1;
BITMAP *p2;
BITMAP *p3;
BITMAP *p4;
BITMAP *p5;
BITMAP *p6;
BITMAP *p7;
BITMAP *q1;
BITMAP *q2;
BITMAP *q3;
BITMAP *q4;
BITMAP *q5;
BITMAP *q6;
BITMAP *q7;
BITMAP *q8;
BITMAP *q9;
BITMAP *q10;
BITMAP *incorrecto;
BITMAP *correcto;
BITMAP *sigue;
BITMAP *excelente;
int main()
{
  allegro_init();
  set_color_depth(16);
  set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 800,600,0, 0);

  install_keyboard();
  install_mouse();
  show_mouse(screen);

  Menu();

  allegro_exit();
  return 0;
}

int Menu()
{
  continuar=true;

  BITMAP *exit;

  fondo = load_bitmap("fondo.bmp", NULL);

  draw_sprite(screen, fondo, 0,0);


  while(!key[KEY_ESC] && continuar)
  {

    if (mouse_x > 300 && mouse_x < 481 && mouse_y > 216 && mouse_y < 263)
    {
        practice = load_bitmap("practice.bmp",NULL);
        draw_sprite(screen, practice, 0,0);

        if (mouse_x > 297 && mouse_x < 474 && mouse_y > 213 && mouse_y < 269)
        {
          if (mouse_b&1)
          {
            Practica1();
          }
         }
    }

    else if (mouse_x  > 300  && mouse_x < 481 && mouse_y > 289  && mouse_y < 342)
    {

      quizz = load_bitmap("quizz.bmp",NULL);
      draw_sprite(screen, quizz,0,0);

      if(mouse_b&1)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          q1 = load_bitmap("q1.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, q1, 0,0);

          if (mouse_b&1)
          {
            if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
            {
              while(!key[KEY_ESC])
              {
                incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
                draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

                if(key[KEY_ENTER])
                {

                  if(!key[KEY_ESC])
                  {

                    return Pregunta2();

                  }

                }
              }
            }

            else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
            {
              while(!key[KEY_ESC])
              {
                incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
                draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

                if(key[KEY_ENTER])
                {

                  if(!key[KEY_ESC])

                  {
                    return Pregunta2();


                  }

                }
              }

            }

            else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
            {
              while(!key[KEY_ESC])
              {



                correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
                draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

                c1=1;



                if(key[KEY_ENTER])
                {

                  if(!key[KEY_ESC])
                  {
                    return Pregunta2();

                   }
                }
              }
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if (mouse_x > 300 && mouse_x < 481 && mouse_y > 372 && mouse_y < 432)
    {

      exit = load_bitmap("exit.bmp",NULL);
      draw_sprite(screen, exit,0,0);

      if(mouse_b&1)
      {
        destroy_bitmap(fondo);
        destroy_bitmap(practice1);
        destroy_bitmap(practice);
        destroy_bitmap(quizz1);
        destroy_bitmap(p2);
        destroy_bitmap(p3);
        destroy_bitmap(p4);
        destroy_bitmap(p5);
        destroy_bitmap(p6);
        destroy_bitmap(p7);
        destroy_bitmap(q1);
        destroy_bitmap(q2);
        destroy_bitmap(q3);
        destroy_bitmap(q4);
        destroy_bitmap(q5);
        destroy_bitmap(q6);
        destroy_bitmap(q7);
        destroy_bitmap(q8);
        destroy_bitmap(q9);
        destroy_bitmap(q10);
        destroy_bitmap(incorrecto);
        destroy_bitmap(correcto);
        destroy_bitmap(sigue);
        destroy_bitmap(excelente);

        continuar = false;

        return 0;
      }
    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen, fondo, 0,0);
    }

  }
  return  1;

}

int Practica1()
{
  finalizar=true;

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    practice1=load_bitmap("p1.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, practice1, 0,0);

    if(mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
         return Menu();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
       return Practica2();
    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,practice1,0,0);
    }

  }

  return 1;

}
int Practica2()
{
  while (!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    p2 =load_bitmap("p2.bmp",NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen,p2,0,0);

    if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
         return Practica1();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
       return Practica3();

    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,p2,0,0);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int  Practica3()
{
  while (!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    p3 =load_bitmap("p3.bmp",NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen,p3,0,0);

    if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
         return Practica2();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
       return Practica4();

    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,p3,0,0);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Practica4()
{
  while (!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    p4 =load_bitmap("p4.bmp",NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen,p4,0,0);

    if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
        return  Practica3();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
      return Practica5();

    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,p4,0,0);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Practica5()
{
while (!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    p5 =load_bitmap("p5.bmp",NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen,p5,0,0);

    if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
         return Practica4();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
       return Practica6();

    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,p5,0,0);
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Practica6()
{

  bool cont=true;
  while (!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    p6 =load_bitmap("p6.bmp",NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen,p6,0,0);

    if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
         return Practica5();
      }
    }

    else if(key[KEY_ENTER])
    {
      rest (100);
      return Practica7();

    }

    else
    {
      draw_sprite(screen,p6,0,0);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
int Practica7()
{
  bool cont=true;

  while(!key[KEY_ESC] && cont)
  {
    p7=load_bitmap("p7.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, p7, 0,0);

     if (mouse_x > 11 && mouse_x < 43 && mouse_y > 61 && mouse_y < 101)
    {
      if (mouse_b&1)
      {
        rest(1000);
         return Practica6();
      }
    }
      else if(mouse_x > 702 && mouse_x < 778 && mouse_y > 300 && mouse_y < 403 )
    {
      if(mouse_b&1)
      {
        if(Menu()== 0)
        {
          cont=false;
          return 0;
        }
      }
    }

  }


  return 1;
}

int Pregunta2()
{
  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q2 = load_bitmap("q2.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q2, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            while(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta3();


            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c2=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta3();
            }
          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {
             if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta3();

            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta3()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q3 = load_bitmap("q3.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q3, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c3=1;


          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta4();

            }
          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta4();

            }
          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta4();

            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta4()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q4 = load_bitmap("q4.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q4, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta5();

            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta5();

            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {



          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c4=1;




          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta5();

            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta5()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q5 = load_bitmap("q5.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q5, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta6();


            }
          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta6();


            }
          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {


          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c5=1;



          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta6();


            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
  return 1;
}
int Pregunta6()
{


  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q6 = load_bitmap("q6.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q6, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta7();

            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c6=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta7();


            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {



          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta7();
            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta7()
{


  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q7 = load_bitmap("q7.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q7, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta8();
            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c7=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta8();
            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta8();
            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta8()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q8 = load_bitmap("q8.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q8, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta9();
            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c8=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta9();
            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {



          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);




          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta9();


            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Pregunta9()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q9 = load_bitmap("q9.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q9, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c9=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta10();

            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return  Pregunta10();


            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {


          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);



          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Pregunta10();


            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;

}
int Pregunta10()
{

  while(!key[KEY_ESC])
  {
    q10 = load_bitmap("q10.bmp", NULL);
    draw_sprite(screen, q10, 0,0);

    if (mouse_b&1)
    {
      if(mouse_x > 94 && mouse_x < 121 && mouse_y >322 && mouse_y < 348 )
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {
          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Contador();
            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if(mouse_x > 95 && mouse_x < 122 && mouse_y > 391 && mouse_y < 418)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])

        {
          correcto= load_bitmap("correcto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, correcto, 0,0);

          c10=1;

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Contador();


            }

          }
        }
      }

      else if (mouse_x > 97 && mouse_x < 124 && mouse_y > 471 && mouse_y < 497)
      {
        while(!key[KEY_ESC])
        {

          incorrecto= load_bitmap("incorrecto.bmp", NULL);
          draw_sprite(screen, incorrecto, 0,0);

          if(key[KEY_ENTER])
          {

            if(!key[KEY_ESC])
            {
              return Contador();


            }

          }
        }
      }

    }
  }

  return 1;
}
int Contador()
{
  bool opcion=true;

  contador=c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6+c7+c8+c9+c10;

  while(!key[KEY_ESC] && opcion)
  {
    if( contador < 7)
    {

      sigue=load_bitmap("sigue.bmp", NULL);
      draw_sprite(screen, sigue, 0,0);
      if(mouse_x > 717 && mouse_x < 776 && mouse_y > 481 && mouse_y < 570 )
      {

        if(mouse_b&1)
        {

          if(Menu()==0)
          {
            opcion=false;
            return 0;
          }

        }
      }

    }
    else
    {

      excelente=load_bitmap("excelente.bmp", NULL);
      draw_sprite(screen, excelente, 0,0);


      if(mouse_x > 690 && mouse_x < 764 && mouse_y > 469 && mouse_y < 570 )
      {

        if(mouse_b&1)
        {

          if(Menu()==0)
          {
            opcion=false;
            return 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 1;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Comment: @eyllanesc nos dijeron que el uso de tantos while, estarían consumiendo los recursos del pc y esto es lo que ocasionaría que se cerrara el programa. Estamos usando la librería allegro, también optamos por destruir la imagenes utilizadas para liberar un poco el espacio pero no ha dado resultado

Comment: @Seitan gracias por copiar el código. ¿Podrías ayudarnos señalando en qué parte de todo tu código deberíamos mirar? ¿Qué parte es la que se ejecuta "*al cabo de determinado tiempo*"? Ayudanos a ayudarte. (esto también debería ir editado en la pregunta). Más información en [mcve].

Comment: Más, de, mil, líneas, de, código. MÁS de mil. Más de mil líneas. ¡1000!. Una propuesta: ¿Por qué no depuras el programa paso a paso y miras donde falla? Seguro que el problema está concentrado en 10 o 20 líneas.

Comment: @Seitan ¿Alguna novedad sobre este problema?

Answer (score 2):

Sin mirar con demasiado detalle veo que los punteros no están inicializados:

```
BITMAP *p4;
```

Luego a posterioridad no sabrás si debes liberar la memoria asociada o no... Por lo que esto:

```
destroy_bitmap(p4);
```

Es susceptible de provocar un error si el bitmap no se ha creado finalmente ya que intentará liberar memoria que no has reservado.